# QR economy: Solution of Ls by QR

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, least-squares, numerical-optimization

In given $\mathbf A$ ($m\times n$ while $m>n$), will do QR-Economy factorization and so:
$\mathbf A=\mathbf {QR}$ [while $\mathbf Q$ ($m\times n$) and $\mathbf R$ ($n\times n$)].
Hwo can i use this factorization for find $\mathbf x^*$ in LS problem?
i tried:
$$
E = \min_{\mathbf x} \|\mathbf{Ax}-\mathbf{b}\|^2= \min_{\mathbf x} \| \mathbf{QRx}-\mathbf{b}\|^2=\dots
$$

In fact, how can i prove that: $J=(\mathbf{ Q b}_1-\mathbf{b})^\top(\mathbf{ Q b}_1-\mathbf{b})$
while $\mathbf b_1=\mathbf{Q}^\top \mathbf{b}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Input**

Start with a matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}_{\rho}$. Restrict the matrix to having full column rank $\rho = n$, and being overdetermined $m>n$. Also, this matrix does not need to be postmultiplied by a permutation matrix to reorder the columns in order to complete the factorization.

$\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{R}$ **factorization**

The $\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{R}$ factorization provides an orthogonal decomposition for the column space
$$
  \mathbf{C}^{m} = 
    \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} \oplus
    \color{red} {\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)}.
$$
The general factorization is
$$
 \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{Q}\,\mathbf{R} = 
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
  \color{blue}{\mathbf{Q}_\mathcal{R}} &
  \color{red} {\mathbf{Q}_\mathcal{N}}
\end{array} \right]
%
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
  \mathbf{R}_{T} \\
  \mathbf{0}
\end{array} \right]
%
$$
with 
$$
\color{blue}{\mathbf{Q}_\mathcal{R}} \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times \rho}, \quad
\color{red}{\mathbf{Q}_\mathcal{N}} \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times (m-\rho)},  \quad\mathbf{R}_{T} \in \mathbb{C}^{\rho\times n}, \quad
\mathbf{0} \in \mathbb{C}^{(n-\rho)\times n}.
$$
The matrix $\mathbf{Q}$ is unitary:
$$
\mathbf{Q}^{*} \mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{Q} \, \mathbf{Q}^{*} = 
\mathbf{I}_{m}
$$
The *thin*, or *reduced*, or *economical*, factorization dispenses with the $\color{red}{null}$ space elements:
$$
\mathbf{A} = \color{blue}{\mathbf{Q}_\mathcal{R}} \mathbf{R}_{T} 
$$

**Method of least squares**

Given a suitable data vector $b\in\mathbb{C}^{m}$, the linear system
$$
 \mathbf{A} x = b
$$
admits the solution
$$
 x_{LS} = \left\{
 x\in\mathbb{C}^{n} \colon
\lVert
 \mathbf{A} x - b
\rVert_{2}^{2}
\text{ is minimized}
\right\}
\tag{1}
$$
Notice that after defining the residual error vector,
$$
 r(x) = \mathbf{A} x - b,
$$
the least squares problem can be restated as minimizing $r^{2},$ the sums of the squares of the residual errors.

$\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{R}$ **and least squares**

Begin by expressing the target matrix in terms of the decomposition:
$$
\lVert
 \mathbf{A} x - b
\rVert
=
\lVert
 \mathbf{Q}\,\mathbf{R} \, x - b
\rVert
$$
Unitary transformations are invariant under the $2-$norm:
$$
\lVert
 \mathbf{Q}\,\mathbf{R} x - b
\rVert
=
\lVert
 \mathbf{Q}^{*} \left( \mathbf{Q}\,\mathbf{R} x - b \right)
\rVert
=
\lVert
 \mathbf{R} \, x - \mathbf{Q}^{*}\,b
\rVert
$$
Let's focus on the thin decomposition of the question, and pry apart the $\color{blue}{range }$ and $\color{red}{null}$ space components of the total error:
$$
\lVert
 \mathbf{R}_{T} \, x - \mathbf{Q}^{*}b
\rVert
=
\Bigg\lVert
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 \mathbf{R}_{T} \\ \mathbf{0}
\end{array} \right]
 \, x - 
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  \color{blue}{\mathbf{Q}^{*}_\mathcal{R}} \\
  \color{red} {\mathbf{Q}^{*}_\mathcal{N}}
\end{array} \right]
\,b
\Bigg\rVert
$$
The total error becomes
$$
  r^{2}(x) =
\Bigg\lVert
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 \mathbf{R}_{T} \\ \mathbf{0}
\end{array} \right]
 \, x - 
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  \color{blue}{\mathbf{Q}^{*}_\mathcal{R}} \\
  \color{red} {\mathbf{Q}^{*}_\mathcal{N}}
\end{array} \right] b
\Bigg\rVert^{2}_{2}
%
=
%
\underbrace{
\Big\lVert
 \mathbf{R}_{T}x -
 \color{blue} {\mathbf{Q}^{*}_\mathcal{R}} b
\Big\rVert^{2}_{2}
}_{\text{control with x}}
%
 +
%
\underbrace{
\Big\lVert
  \color{red} {\mathbf{Q}^{*}_\mathcal{N}} b
\Big\rVert^{2}_{2}}_{\text{no control}}
$$

**Least squares solution via** $\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{R}$

There are two pieces. One piece can be controlled by adjusting the solution vector $x$; in fact, this piece can be driven to 0 via 
$$
\mathbf{R}_{T}x -
 \color{blue} {\mathbf{Q}^{*}_\mathcal{R}} b = 0
\qquad \Rightarrow \qquad
\boxed{ \color{blue} {x_{LS}} = \color{blue} {
\mathbf{R}^{-1}_{T} \mathbf{Q}^{*}_\mathcal{R} b}}
$$
The residual error, the error that cannpt be removed is 
$$
 r^{2}\left( x_{LS} \right) = \Big\lVert
  \color{red} {\mathbf{Q}^{*}_\mathcal{N}} b
\Big\rVert^{2}_{2}
$$
This is the magnitude of the portion of the data vector extending into the $\color{red}{null}$ space $\color{red} {\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)}$.